# Angular 2 and ng2semantic compilation error

Tags: javascript, angular, semantic-ui

I am triying to integrate Angular 2 with ng2SemanticUI library  according to the **Getting Started** section. I have successfull installed the library and added the required css files. Furthermore I have imported the main modules to my **app.module.ts** file without problems.

The problem arises with the SystemJS configuration step:

```
 System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  'app': 'app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  'ng2-semantic-ui': 'npm:ng2-semantic-ui/bundles/ng2-semantic-ui.umd.min.js',
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

});

My application throws a compilation error.

[image: Error here!]

Thanks.

Comment: what's the npm path in your config ? please post the full config file.

Comment: Did you run 'npm install' after adding that line???????????????/

Comment: @chairmanmow I did it but still not working (same error).

Comment: @AhmedMusallam done!

Comment: @AntonioRivera do you have `ng2-semantic-ui` in your package.json? did you run `npm install --save ng2-semantic-ui` ?? same for `rxjs`?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Yes, I have the `ng2-semantic-ui`in my package.json file. Yes, I run the `npm install --save ng2-semantic-ui` and the same for rxjs but the problem persists.